# Get all has many from an activerecord hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model **Campain** which has many **Media**.

I do this:

```
Campain.all.medias
```

But get this error:

```
 undefined method `medias' for #<Array:0x00000004bbaf40>
```

How can I get all medias from `Campain.all`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The better approach is to use this code:

```
Campaign.includes(:media).map(&:media)
```

(Used English grammar, I hope you get the main idea). This will get all in two requests.

---EDIT---

If media - is `has_many` assosiation, indeed the return will be in form: `[[...],[..]]` so in that case use `flaten` to make it just simple array.
In the case when there needed all `Medium`s that are for all `Camplaign` use arrays `group` method to collect unique or just simple `uniq`. This approach to use Rails classes is preferable, as it is more general and configurable, for example it will apply any default scopes, that may be on `Campaign`.

Comment: Since map returns an array, and Campaign has many Media, this will give you an array in which each element is an array of Media.

Comment: Yes i just have to use Campaign.includes(:media).map(&:media)
.first.order('price asc') for example

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete Dylans Post - I upgraded to Rails 3.1.1 today. My app has ~60 Models and one of these was called `Media` and it worked well eaven when it was bad english. So I upgraded and I think they patched the `pluralize`method. I wasnt able to call the medias actions and rails said the table 'media' doesnt exist which was the moment I realised my table was called `media` because I used rails 3.0.3 to create the model. I renamed the model, controller and views names, updated the routes from `resources :medias` to `ressources :media` as a quick fix and it worked again!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for all Media that has an associated Campaign, you should query via the Media object, not the Campaign object.  This will give you one array of Media objects, and only takes one query (assuming your Media object has a `campaign_id` [that is, `Media :belongs_to :campaign`]).

```
Media.where("campaign_id is not null").all
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as Rails is concerned, the singular of Media is "medium" and the plural is "media", so just try `media`. However, `all` will still return an array, which you can't call `media` on anyway. So you probably want:

```
@campaigns = Campaign.all
@media = Medium.where(:campaign_id => @campaigns.collect(&:id))
```

or this (similar to another answer, but you need to flatten the results):

```
Campaign.includes(:media).map(&:media).flatten
```

Comment: `Campaign.all` returns an array of Campaign objects.  The Campaigns themselves have media, not the array.

Comment: oops! not enough coffee today.